# Azure loadbalancer IP overrides the client IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kong

I need to be able to log the source IP address trying accessing to my application.
Problem is that I have the current setup:

```
service load balancer-->kong-->myy application
```

Kong is very good and automatically adds an "X-Forwarded-for" header to requests coming to my application so that I don't get Kong's IP...but this header only contains the load balancer IP!

What should happen is that in that header there should be the client's IP...is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` in the service definition, this will preserve clients ip.

Reading [here](https://www.asykim.com/blog/deep-dive-into-kubernetes-external-traffic-policies) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/607)

Comment: Sweet! Does this work also with the new ingress type? Currently I'm using the LoadBalancer so I don't care too much